In my Blazor server side app, I want that when the user clicks somewhere on the page, the last focused button shall be refocused again
In my Blazor server side app I have buttons in my  razor pages, that opens the related subpages. When a button is clicked then it gets a focus style as defined in my css. When the user then clicks elsewhere in the page (but not another button) the last clicked button loses its focus. I want that the last clicked button shall be refocused immediately again when cliccked elsewhere then a button.
For achieving this, I have tried following , but didn't work:
<button class="icon-button" onblur="this.focus();" @onclick="SubPage1">

What could be the solution?

You could try use css dynamically.Create entity for button in order to control the focus state.
<style>
    .unfocus {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .focus {

        background-color: purple; 
    }
</style>

@foreach (var item in myButtons)
{
        <button class="@(item.Focus?"focus":"unfocus")" @onfocus="@(()=>{myButtons.ForEach(x=>x.Focus=false);item.Focus=true;})" @onclick="()=>{SubPage1(item.Id);}">@item.Id </button>
}

@code {
    List<MyButton> myButtons = new List<MyButton>{
        new MyButton{Id="buttonA"},
        new MyButton{Id="buttonB"},
        new MyButton{Id="buttonC"}
    };
    private void SubPage1(string buttonId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{buttonId} is clicked");
    }
    public class MyButton
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool Focus { get; set; } = false;
    }
}


